# How does excitations in quantum field works?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

1. How does excitations in a quantum field propagate? An analogy to this is ripples on a pund. However, these ripples extends outwards in a 360 degree circle, which is not how particles behave. *Does the excited state travel in a straight line in one direction?*
2. Why is the excitations in quantum field viewed as a particle? For example, an electron is excitation in the electron field. How does excitations even resemples point like particles? Can this be visualised in the following way? *"A quantum field (for example an electron field) contains all the properties of the particle, but the particle itself don't become noticeable until a region of the field is excited. Only then we can measure its properties"?*
3. *Can regions of quantum fields interact when it is in the ground state?*

Answer (score 1):

Particles are elusive things in quantum mechanics. When you first learned the Schrodinger equation for a free particle you probably learned that the solutions are infinite plane waves, which don't look much like particles. And we find a similar situation in quantum field theory.

If you consider a free field, i.e. non-interacting particles, then the quantum states of the field are the [Fock states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_state). These represent the particles, so applying the creation operator to a Fock state creates a particle and applying the annihilation operator destroys a particle.

But these states are very similar to the infinite plane wave solution that we get for the Schrodinger equation. That is the state has a well defined momentum and infinite uncertainty in position. You use the analogy of ripples radiating outwards, but this is a superposition of momentum states so you'd have to construct it by combining states. This applies in both QFT and QM.

Likewise, if you want a localised particle you have to construct it by combining the momentum states to create a wavepacket, and again this is the case both for QFT and QM.

I've specifically restricted the discussion to a free field because once we include interactions between particles we can no longer solve for the particle states so we cannot say what the states are. The best we can do is analyse the scattering using perturbation theory. So when we talk about electrons, photons etc we need to be clear these are the states in the limit of infinite separation, so the interaction goes to zero.

I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking in your third question.